# Use regular expression in autoblogged to change date format

Tags: regex, wordpress, autoblogged

I have a a feed who's date is formatted like 'D, d M Y G:i:s e'

Autoblogged has a reg expression engine.

What is the regular expression to convert 'D, d M Y G:i:s e' to 'F j, Y'?

Again I want to convert 'Fri, 20 Apr 2012 12:00:00 EST' to 'April 20, 2012' where the date is stored in variable %:pubDate%. I'm using Autoblogged for Wordpress.

Comment: A regular expression can't easily get 'April' out of 'Apr'.  You'll wind up with 13 regular expressions, one to move things around, and one for each month to expand the abbreviation.  Does Autoblogged not have any other tools for this?

Comment: They have a search and replace feature, which can also use regex.

Answer (score 0):

Regex cannot *convert* strings, but it can find and parse them.
This regex will do what you want.

Put this in the "Search for" field (assuming that the dates are formatted *exactly* like `Fri, 20 Apr 2012 12:00:00 EST`):

```
[a-zA-Z]{3}, ([0-9]{1,2}) ([a-zA-Z]{3}) ([0-9]{4}) [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2} [a-zA-Z]{3}
```

And this in the "Replace with" field:

```
$2 $1, $3
```

See this for a demonstration: http://regex101.com/r/tP6hU7

You can then replace

- `Jan(?:uary)?` with `January`,
- `Feb(?:ruary)?` with `February`,
- etc.

Input: `Fri, 20 Apr 2012 12:00:00 EST`
Output: `April 20, 2012`